# How to fill missing values based on neighboring polygons in R?

Tags: r, purrr, r-sf

Suppose the following dataset and add some missing values (only for illustration):

```
library(dplyr)
library(sf)

demo(nc, ask = FALSE, verbose = FALSE)
nc$AREA[c(30, 45)] <- NA
```

I can get all the neighboring polygons for each county:

```
nc %>% mutate(
   INTERSECT = purrr::map(.x = geometry, .f = st_intersects, y = st_geometry(nc))
)
```

This gives me a list of the indices of neighboring counties for each row. Now I'd like to fill the missing area values with the mean area of neighboring polygons. How would I use these indices to take the mean over the corresponding rows?

Comment: what does nc look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
index <- st_touches(nc, nc)

output <- nc %>% 
  mutate(AREA = ifelse(is.na(AREA),
                             apply(index, 1, function(i){mean(.$AREA[i])}),
                             AREA))

output$AREA[c(30, 45)]

[1] 0.1510 0.1335
```

**Checking the answers:**

Indices for the two polygons' neighbors.

```
index[c(30, 45)]

[[1]]
[1] 13 14 29 37 48

[[2]]
[1] 44 87
```

Find the areas manually.

```
mean(output$AREA[index[[30]]])

[1] 0.151

mean(output$AREA[index[[45]]])

[1] 0.1335
```