Unsuccessful in exporting data from 1 sf object to the boundaries of another sf object , using st_intersection
I am having trouble aggregating the data in 1 spatial polygon file at the level of an overlapping spatial polygon file. Specifically, I have a shapefile of India's 1970 districts. I ALSO have a shapefile of India's 2020 districts, with district-level soil data merged in. I read both shapefiles in using readOGR() and then turned them into sf objects using st_as_sf(). I have put that code at the BOTTOM of this post, as I assume it's probably irrelevant.
After I have both the shapefiles (soilshape.sf is the 2020 district coundaries shapefile with the soil variables, eg Zn_s is a soil variable, and dist1970.sf is the 1970 district boundaries shapefile), I can run this code below to see the spatial overlap, link to picture here.
# successful! i can map 1970 districts over 2020 districts.
ggplot(data = soilshape.sf) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = Zn_s)) +
  geom_sf(data = dist1970.sf, lwd = .5, color = "#000000",fill = NA)

However, next I want to extract the 2020 district-level soil data to the 1970 districts... many 1970 districts overlap multiple 2020 districts, as you can see in the pic, so I want to do a weighted mean of the 2020 districts overlaid on each 1970 district, the weight being their area within the 1970 district. ChatGPT semi-helped me put together the code below.. The overlay didn't work until I put in sf_use_s2(FALSE), but maybe that's causing a problem? (See addendum; no it's not.) And I couldn't figure out how to merge the vector of data within result back into an sf object, by ID, so I merged it to the sp version of my 1970 district shapefile, and then converted that again into an sf object.
# Perform spatial overlay to find overlapping districts
sf_use_s2(FALSE)
overlay <- st_intersection(soilshape.sf, dist1970.sf)

# Calculate area of each intersection
overlay$intersection_area <- st_area(overlay)

# Calculate weighted zinc mean within each 1970 district
# Note that ID is the unique ID for each polygon in dist1970.sf
result <- overlay %>%
  dplyr::group_by(ID) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(wZn_s = sum(Zn_s * intersection_area) / sum(intersection_area))

# Join the result back to dist1970.. i can only figure out how to do with the sp object
# note: x = the shapefile (ID in dist1970), y= the data.frame (ID in result)
dist1970.zn <- merge(dist1970, result, by.x ='ID', by.y ='ID', all.x=TRUE)  # keep districts NOT in result

# sf object again
dist1970.zn.sf <- st_as_sf(dist1970.zn)

In any case, this code above runs, but the output is wrong. First of all, 105 of the 1970 districts are missing soil info (sum(is.na(dist1970.zn@data$wZn_s)) is 105, of 386 districts). That can't be right. Also, I'm unable to map the wZn_s variable. This code:
ggplot(data = dist1970.zn.sf) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = wZn_s)) 

returns the error:
Error in `geom_sf()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `scale_type.units()`:
! Variable of class 'units' found, but 'units' package is not attached.
  Please, attach it using 'library(units)' to properly show scales with units.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

Help? What am I doing wrong when it comes to this spatial overlay?
Addendum: I have now tried mending a broken polygon (?) via st_make_valid() and re-running overlay <- st_intersection(soilshape.sf, dist1970.sf) with sf_use_s2(TRUE). The result is the same: 104 districts missing wZn_s data in the result object, and same error if I try to map dist1970.zn.sf. So apparently using sf_use_s2(FALSE) was NOT the problem.
CODE FOR BRINGING IN BOTH OF THE ORIGINAL SF FILES (PROB NOT RELEVANT BUT JUST IN CASE):
#==============================================================================#
## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## 
## 2020 shapefile + merge in the dist-level created above  =====================
## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## 
#==============================================================================#

# 2020 shapefile
setwd("/Users/bevis.16/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-TheOhioStateUniversity/BoxLeah/Projects/1 FINISHED/Kuznets/zenodo/data_raw/shpfiles")
dist2020 <- readOGR(dsn="districtshp2020", layer="output") # 20 district

# merge in district-level soil & DHS child data 
soildata <-  read.dta13("/Users/bevis.16/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-TheOhioStateUniversity/BoxLeah/Projects/1 FINISHED/Kuznets/distlevel.dta")

# note: x = the shapefile (distcode in dist2020), y= the data.frame (distcode in distlevel.dta)
soilshape <- merge(dist2020, soildata, by.x ='distcode', by.y ='distcode', all.x=TRUE)  # keep districts NOT in distlevel.dta
#soilshape <- merge(dist2020, soildata, by.x ='distcode', by.y ='distcode', all.x=FALSE)  # keep only districts in distlevel.dta

# make an sf objet out of dist2020 
soilshape.sf <- st_as_sf(soilshape)

#==============================================================================#
## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## 
## Read 1970 shapefile, Collapse to unique 1970 districts ======================
## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## 
#==============================================================================#

setwd("/Users/bevis.16/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-TheOhioStateUniversity/BoxLeah/Projects/GR Inequality/Data/Geospatial")
distVDS <- readOGR(dsn="Districts_For_VDS", layer="india70again") # 20 district

# Make dist1970 unique by 1970 district ID to match 1966 districts:

  # Convert SpatialPolygons to data frame
  distVDS.df <- as(distVDS, "data.frame")

  # Aggregate and sum district area (distVDS.df[, 1]) by the 1970 district code (DISTCODE)
  # (For some reason multiple polygons are labeled with 1 1970 district, so merging)
  distVDS.df.agg <- aggregate(distVDS.df[, 1], list(ID=distVDS@data$DISTCODE), sum)
  row.names(distVDS.df.agg) <- as.character(distVDS.df.agg$ID)

  # Dissolve the actual shapefile to merge together by DISTCODE
  distVDS_mrg <- unionSpatialPolygons(distVDS,ID=distVDS@data$DISTCODE)

  # Give the shapefile that merged area attribute 
  dist1970 <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(distVDS_mrg, distVDS.df.agg)

# make dist1970 an sf object 
dist1970.sf <- st_as_sf(dist1970)

# remove clutter 
rm(distVDS, distVDS_mrg, distVDS.df, distVDS.df.agg)

# copy coordinate system of 2020 shapefile to 1970 shapefile (had none, before)
dist1970.sf <- st_set_crs(dist1970.sf, st_crs(soilshape.sf))


Based on your question, it sounds like maybe you want to do an areal-weighted interpolation rather than an overlay (e.g., if district A from 1970 has 60% of its area now encompassed by district B in 2020 and the other 40% of district C in 2020, then district A's Zn_s = 0.6* district B Zn_s + 0.4*district C Zn_s); have you tried sf::st_interpolate_aw() yet?

Yes that is exactly what I want to do -- thanks! I guess chatGPT led me astray. I am very not sf knowledgeable; just started using it, used to use sp. Will try but if you think you can provide helpful explicit code would be very grateful!

So I've created a mock dataset here to illustrate areal-weighted interpolation using sf (you may also try using the areal package written by Dr. Chris Prener at St. Louis University, but sf should be sufficient for your use case). I've used the tidycensus package to grab some U.S. Census data at the census tract level on the foreign-born population in Dallas County, Texas. Census tracts are a great example as they can change every decennial census as the population grows or declines.
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(tidycensus)
library(ggplot2)

dallas_foreign_2020 <- get_acs(
  geography = "tract",
  year = 2020,
  # Total foreign-born population as an example
  variables = "B05002_013",
  state = "TX",
  county = "Dallas",
  geometry = TRUE
) |>
  # Used crsuggest::suggest_crs() for best CRS
  st_transform(6583)

dallas_foreign_2010 <- get_acs(
  geography = "tract",
  year = 2010,
  # Total foreign-born population as an example
  variables = "B05002_013",
  state = "TX",
  county = "Dallas",
  geometry = TRUE
) |>
  select(estimate) |>
  st_transform(6583)

dallas_foreign_interpol <- st_interpolate_aw(
  dallas_foreign_2010,
  dallas_foreign_2020,
  # uses weighted sums; set to FALSE to use weighted means
  extensive = TRUE
) |>
  mutate(GEOID = dallas_foreign_2020$GEOID)

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(
    data = dallas_foreign_interpol,
    aes(fill = estimate)
  ) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "PuOr", direction = -1) +
  labs(fill = "Total Foreign-Born \nPopulation") +
  theme_void()

For areal interpolation to be accurate, your two sf objects must use the same coordinate reference system (CRS). You can check the CRS of each object with sf::st_crs() and if needed, change the CRS using sf::st_transform(). Depending on the type of variable(s) you have, when using sf::st_interpolate_aw(), you must set extensive=TRUE for count-based data (e.g., population counts) or extensive=FALSE for percentage- or rate-based data (e.g., population density). Again, the areal package has a helpful tutorial and explanation on this.
My example data is count-based, so I've used extensive areal interpolation in this scenario to estimate from 2010 geographies --> 2020 geographies. If I had used something like the % of residents per tract that are foreign-born, I would need to use intensive interpolation.
Do note that sf produces two warnings in this scenario: 1) st_interpolate_aw assumes attributes are constant or uniform over areas of x and 2) number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length. The former is due to a major assumption of areal interpolation: namely, that attributes are evenly distributed over space (which is rarely the case in real life--after all, the city is much more densely populated than the suburbs). The latter is due to the increase in the number of census tracts in 2020, mainly because of the population boom Dallas County is experiencing. This may be the case with your data as well (e.g., more districts in 2020 than in 1970). All in all, the end result looks like:


This is so beautiful! This function works for me, EXCEPT that if there any NA value for one of the smaller polygons, the larger, aggregated polygon in the object created by st_interpolate_aw() takes NA. But in almost all cases (you can see in the map I linked at top) the 2020 NA value is a small part of the larger 1970 district area, and I'd prefer to ignore the NA value and create a mean (using extensive = FALSE) of the non-nA values. I see this problem mentioned here (https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/830) but don't understand the solution. Can you help? How do I address?

Also: when I run a = st_interpolate_aw(soilshape.sf["Zn_s"], dist1970.sf, extensive = FALSE),  the sf object a has 1 less polygon than the sf object dist1970. I imagine this is because there is no overlap between soilshape.sf and 1 polygon in dist1970.sf. However, because st_interpolate_aw() doesn't return any of the data within dist1970.sf, I don't know how to merge that data in "a" back to my IDs in dist1970.sf. Which is necessary. The order won't be identical. Any ideas? I don't suppose there is any way to get a list of the dist1970.sf IDs that are unique to the new sf object?

For the NA values, depending on what your data is supposed to represent, it may make sense to replace those NA values with 0, as suggested in the Github thread above. As for your newly interpolated data.frame a, there's an additional argument to st_interpolate_aw() that you can set: keep_NA=TRUE. That way it'll keep that 1 polygon that has no areal overlap. I also included mutate(GEOID = dallas_foreign_2020$GEOID) so the interpolated sf object would have a unique identifier I could relate back to my 2020 census tracts - the same trick might work for you to merge back with dist1970.

Revising my last 2 comments. Thank you! (1) Replacing NA values w/ 0 only works for  sums (extensive = TRUE), I think. But I've followed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62915873/how-to-fill-missing-values-based-on-neighboring-polygons-in-r to fill in missing values before st_interpolate_aw. (2) When I try your mutate code, I get an error in stopifnot(), argument ID = dist1970.sf$ID -- ID must be size 385 or 1, not 386. I find this interesting because dist1970.sf is 386 obs, but the object I get from st_interpolate_aw is 385. Any idea what's causing this error / how to deal with it?

should I start a new question regarding my inability to use your mutate() trick to retain the "to" ID? I know this relates to the fact that my "to" object (dist1970.sf) is 386x3, but the object being created is for some reason only 385x2 -- I'm loosing one of the 1970 polygons somehow, and I don't know which / why. I really really need to figure this out ASAP, though.

You're correct - mutate() only works in the example above because the number of rows is the same. keep_NA=TRUE does work with intensive areal interpolations, though, try the following as an example:
`nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"))
g <- st_make_grid(nc, n = c(10,5))
a1 <- st_interpolate_aw(nc["BIR74"], g, extensive = FALSE, keep_NA = TRUE)`.
One shortcoming of st_interpolate_aw() is that the process is rather opaque. I will post a new answer using the areal package instead.

Thank you this keep_NA=TRUE works!! I should have realized this before from the help file. Thank you so much.

The only remaining problem is that I'd like to pass through na.rm=TRUE, which I think a fellow is working on (https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/830), but doesn't seem to have worked yet. Meanwhile, I'm just filling in gaps BEFORE the interpolation, non-ideal, but even that process is problematic, as I've posted about (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78259399/fill-missing-values-based-on-the-non-missing-neighboring-polygons-in-r). If you could re-open that question or if you have the ability to add the na.rm=TRUE option to st_interpolate_aw, either would be awesome!

Here's a clean(er) answer using the areal package, which allows a bit more granular control over the steps going on "underneath the hood" than sf::st_interpolate_aw.
As before, we'll grab the foreign-born population at the census tract-level for Dallas County. We'll be interpolating to the city limits to show a case where 1) we can keep a unique identifier column for later use in joins and other operations; and 2) the number of rows between the source and target geometries are vastly different. In this case, the city will have 1 observation, whereas the county will have 645 observations. This time, we'll also use the share of the total population that is foreign-born to demonstrate intensive interpolation, as that's more similar to your use case.
library(areal)
library(sf)
library(tidycensus)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Create source geographies
dallas_county <- get_acs(
  geography = "tract",
  year = 2020,
  # As before, total foreign-born population
  variables = "B05002_013",
  state = "TX",
  county = "Dallas",
  geometry = TRUE,
  # New summary variable: total population
  summary_var = "B05002_001"
) |>
  mutate(pct_foreign_born = case_when(
    summary_est==0 ~ 0,
    .default = 100*(estimate/summary_est)
  )) |>
  select(
    -variable,
    -ends_with("moe")
  ) |>
  # Used crsuggest::suggest_top_crs() for best CRS
  # Note use of projected CRS for planar geometries; lat/lon cannot be used to calculate area
  st_transform(32138)

# Create target geometries
city_of_dallas <- tigris::places(
  state = "TX",
  year = 2020,
  filter_by = dallas_county
) |>
  # select relevant columns
  select(GEOID, NAMELSAD, geometry) |>
  st_transform(32138)

We'll also introduce a polygon with an NA value for our pct_foreign_born variable to more closely match your real data. I've selected a census tract that, based on previous work, I know falls within the City of Dallas limits.
dallas_county <- dallas_county |>
  mutate(pct_foreign_born = case_when(
    GEOID=="48113011500" ~ NA,
    .default = pct_foreign_born
  ))

Then we'll use the helper function ar_validate() to make sure our interpolation goes smoothly. This functions ensures that the CRS between our two sf objects match, that they're planar, etc.
areal::ar_validate(
  dallas_county,
  city_of_dallas,
  varList = "pct_foreign_born",
  method = "aw",
  verbose = TRUE
)

# A tibble: 7 × 2
  test                            result
  <chr>                           <lgl> 
1 sf Objects                      TRUE  
2 CRS Match                       TRUE  
3 CRS is Planar                   TRUE  
4 Polygon Geometries              TRUE  
5 Variables Exist in Source       TRUE  
6 No Variable Conflicts in Target TRUE  
7 Overall Evaluation              TRUE 

Lastly, we perform the actual areal interpolation using areal::aw_interpolate().  Note that areal allows us to specify unique identifier columns in our target and source geometries using tid and sid, respectively. This should allow you to retain dist1970.sf$ID in the interpolated result. For intensive interpolations, we also specify weight="sum" and pass a vector of quoted variable names that are to be treated as spatially intensive to the intensive argument.
# Generate interpolated geographies
foreign_born_dallas_city <- aw_interpolate(
  # target geography
  city_of_dallas,
  # Unique ID within target geography
  tid = GEOID,
  # source geography where the data to be interpolated comes from
  source = na.omit(dallas_county),
  # Unique ID within source geography
  sid = GEOID,
  weight = "sum",
  output = "sf",
  intensive = "pct_foreign_born"
)

I've specified source = na.omit(dallas_county) so that NA values are not propagated to the target geometries. The result when printing foreign_born_dallas_city is then:
Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 3 fields
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 740710.2 ymin: 2105977 xmax: 790299.6 ymax: 2152298
Projected CRS: NAD83 / Texas North Central
    GEOID    NAMELSAD pct_foreign_born                       geometry
1 4819000 Dallas city         20.61177 MULTIPOLYGON (((778005.7 21...

We've retained our unique ID column and the value of pct_foreign_born in our target geometry is not NA! Hope this helps!
